# ASP.NET Core application published onto IIS doesn't recognize AD user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, iis, active-directory

When I run application on IIS from Visual Studio 2019, it works normally.

I'm using Windows Authentication and AD groups.
If i use `@User.Identity.Name` it show me my *domain\username*.

But when I publish the app onto an IIS which is hosted on a Windows Server 2008 R2 then

- the `@User.Identity.Name` shows nothing (`null` I guess)
- and the `@User.IsAuthenticated` shows `false`.

I have set Windows Authentication to enabled in IIS.

When I want to enter page where I used:
`[Authorize(Roles = StaticDetails.RoleUzivatel + "," + StaticDetails.RoleAdmin)]`
it shows me error 404 page not found.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();

    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{Area=Uzivatel}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Comment: Is the IIS server joined to the AD domain? I think that is necessary for Windows auth to work.

Comment: Yes, this application server is part of  AD.... But also when I run app localy from .exe file it doesnt recognize user...

Comment: Have you only enabled Windows authentication in iis? how did you configure windows authentication in asp.net core? here a link about how to configure windows authentication in asp.net core for you as a reference: [Configure Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio).